# Why is AngularJS Controller not working on my pc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, controller, angularjs-controller

I have started learning MEAN Stack and wanted to try some code but AngularJs Controller is not working on my PC. I have windows 10 on my Acer Aspire V Nitro.

Can anyone please help. Will be highly obliged.

My code - 
(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appname">

  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="appname" ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

(app.js)

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}]);
```

Both the files are in C://test folder.

Thank You.

Comment: could you make sure couple of things 1) does all js files loaded in browser 2) any error in console?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `ng-app` in your code, in the `div` and in the `html`.Try to remove one of them(I advice to remove the one in the `div`).

**See the code below**

```js
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appname">

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Removed it but still not working. It is saying `{{greeting.text}}, world`

Comment: Specifying `ng-app` twice is incorrect, but bdw second is anyway going to be ignored.. Issue must be something else. You answer doesn't make sense

Comment: Is there anything that I need to install first anything specific before running it. Right now I have installed nodejs and mongodb and have saved a page of angular.min.js version 1.5.8 in the same folder

Comment: @ShawnikRaghav check you have added `script.js` but in the description your file is in the `app.js`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan thanx a lot! It was the problem. Sorry about the mess. Actually i was running two seperate app codes.

Answer (score 0):

You include a file, called **script.js**, when it should be **app.js**. Make sure that this:

```
...
<script src="script.js"></script>
...
```

points to the js, where the controller is registered.

Answer (score 0):

According to you your `angular` code lies in the file `app.js` but it's not attached with your `index.html` page so place it as:

```
<script src='app.js'></script>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank u so much for taking your time out and helping me. Sorry about the mess, I was running 2 codes at one time and got confused but still I am getting issues with other code.